Permission 'run.services.setIamPolicy' denied on resource * (or resource may not exist)
Whenever I try to deploy a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Cloud Function, I encounter this error. However, when I check the dashboard, the function has deployed correctly.
Preparing function...
.done.
Updating function (may take a while)...
[Build].....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................warning
[Service]........................................................................warning
Completed with warnings:
Warning: G] *** Improve build performance by generating and committing package-lock.json.
  [INFO] A new revision will be deployed serving with 100% traffic.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[Permission 'run.services.setIamPolicy' denied on resource 'projects/my-project-abcdef/locations/us-central1/services/my-function-name' (or resource may not exist).]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


My IAM service account has the following permissions:

Cloud Build Service Account
Cloud Functions Developer
Kubernetes Engine Admin
Kubernetes Engine Cluster Viewer
Service Account User
Storage Admin

And in the Cloud Build settings panel, the IAM service account has both the Cloud Functions and Service Accounts services enabled.

I found out adding Cloud Functions Admin role to the IAM service account fixed the issue. I'm not sure if that's the suggested way but it works.
